# Populating Tableview with Mixed classes(JavaFx)

Tags: database, class, javafx, tableview

I have been going through multiple questions on here about this but cannot find one that fits my circumstances.

I have a program that allows you to schedule meetings. It connects out to a sql database where everything is stored. I have a main screen that pulls information from my appointment class(date & time) and the customer class (customer ID & name) i know this will not populate correctly because the table cannot be two classes. Is there anyway I can get this to work properly. I have a feeling it's super easy that I can implement into one of my java classes. Feel free to ask any questions if something isn't clear!

Thanks!

Comment: Create another class. `Model(id, name, date, time)`

Comment: I don't see why you would use both as items in the same `TableView`. There doesn't seem to be any intersection between the properties of the appointment and the customer. Sure the customer you want to meet could be associated with an appointment but this doesn't mean there would be 2 types of items in the `TableView` but instead the appointment would get a property of type customer...

Comment: Perhaps it would help to provide a small amount of sample data, what you would want the table to look like with those sample data, and precisely what problems you have encountered implementing it.

Comment: Well I see my code didn't format properly. https://ibb.co/cMe9hS  ---that link goes to a database layout that I used to create my classes. I hope this helps you understand. As the way the program stands is that we need to be able to let the user log in and have a "calendar" that shows the time date and the customer. They should also be able to add new customers into the database, as well as new appointments, as well as get appointment reminders. @James_D

Comment: here is a link to a snapshot of my program. It shows all of the classes as well as the main screen where the tableview is ----https://ibb.co/gNULp7